# QEMU/KVM: failed to attach usb-host device

Tags: android, linux, qemu, kvm, libusb

I have this device that will be disconnect and reconnect again when `libusb_reset_device`, how can I forward it to VM. I've look at [source code](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=hw/usb/host-libusb.c;hb=bec9c64ef7be8063f1192608b83877bc5c9ea217#l1447), and it call `libusb_reset_device`.

this is log trace when I attach that device:

```
1720@1518601481.571033:usb_host_open_started dev 2:3
1720@1518601481.571164:usb_host_detach_kernel dev 2:3, if 0
1720@1518601481.578244:usb_host_parse_config dev 2:3, value 1, active 1
1720@1518601481.578276:usb_host_parse_interface dev 2:3, num 0, alt 0, active 1
1720@1518601481.578287:usb_host_parse_endpoint dev 2:3, ep 1, in, bulk, active 1
. . .
1720@1518601481.579041:usb_host_open_success dev 2:3
1720@1518601481.694268:usb_host_reset dev 2:3
1720@1518601482.072884:usb_host_reset dev 2:3
1720@1518601482.072954:usb_host_close dev 2:3
1720@1518601482.073045:usb_host_auto_scan_enabled
```

this is dmesg log of the host (not the VM)

```
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1782, idProduct=5d24
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: Product: Spreadtrum
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Spreadtrum
Feb 14 16:43:25 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 20161122200747
Feb 14 16:43:26 win-pc kernel: usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 14 16:43:26 win-pc kernel: scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
Feb 14 16:43:26 win-pc kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Feb 14 16:43:26 win-pc kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Feb 14 16:43:27 win-pc kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-CD Gadget   0310 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 14 16:43:27 win-pc kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
Feb 14 16:43:27 win-pc kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb 14 16:44:41 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Feb 14 16:44:41 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1782, idProduct=5d24
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: Product: Spreadtrum
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Spreadtrum
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 20161122200747
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 14 16:44:42 win-pc kernel: scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
Feb 14 16:44:43 win-pc kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-CD Gadget   0310 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
. . .
```

as you can see, the device will disconnect itself and reconnect again after that

How can I forward this kind of device to VM

EDIT 1:

If you wonder what device is it, it is an android phone. I want to pass it to VM so I can use `adb` on the VM

EDIT 2:

my timezone is UTC+7. you can see the correlation between qemu trace log and dmesg log based on the timestamp

EDIT 3:

I've tried using `device_add usb-host,vendorid=1782,productid=5d24` instead of using `hostbus` and `hostaddr`, this lead to infinite loop of:

- qemu try to claim the device
- device disconnect itself and reconnect again
- qemu try to claim the device again
- device disconnect itself and reconnect again
- and so on ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: okay, how I move this thread?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the USB device in QEMU, we need to make sure that user running QEMU has the necessary permissions to access the USB device connected to host machine.

I assume that udev rules are already taken into consideration.

I found a bug within the "qemu-system-x86_64" QEMU binary that is linked to the libusb library. Consequently, I made the decision to compile the QEMU source code with the latest version of the libusb library. Found some useful forum that leads to this decision [link1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/problem-passing-through-usb-devices-in-qemu-4175492519/) [link2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/trying-to-wrestle-with-usb-permissions-and-passing-through-devices-qemu-vms-4175672319/)

Please follow the steps mentioned here:

**Build libusb source code and install properly on your ubuntu system**

```
git clone https://github.com/libusb/libusb.git    
git checkout tags/v1.0.22 -b V1.0.22    
./configure --enable-udev --disable-static    
make    
sudo make install
```

**Build Qemu source code**

```
git clone https://github.com/qemu/qemu.git    
git checkout -b stable-6.1 origin/stable-6.1    
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-libusb --enable-kvm    
make -j16    
sudo make install
```